# React - Map() with array of objects and useRef for get id of the element clicked

Tags: reactjs

Problem. Of beginner. But not for me. I dry. I retrieve an array of objects, which consists of the posts in my database. I iterate with map(). I put that in the render. Everything rolls, except that, when at onClick, I go to retrieve the ref of the element by to useRef() and current in order to be able to then put in my fetch request the identifier of the post in the URL address for the comparison back side with req. `params.id` when editing, deleting, liking all that, I come across the same ID, the first or the last I know more, but the same. However, in DevTools, all the posts are well referenced, DOM HTML side too, so I guess I do something with useRef(), I look everywhere on the net without finding anything.

I specify that I am under React.

My code:

```js
let refPost = useRef(null) let displayPosts = dataResultPosts.map((post, i) => (
<AllPostsAndModals id={post._id} ref={refPost} key={post._id}>
  <BlockAuthor>
    <DivAuthor>
      <PictureUserPost>
        <Image src={pictureUser || ' '} alt="photo profil utilisateur"></Image>
      </PictureUserPost>
      <NameAuthor key={post._id}>{post.firstname} {post.lastname}</NameAuthor>
      <DivIconOption>
        <BlockIconOption>
          <p style={{marginTop: '2px', marginRight: '2px'}}>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEllipsis} fontSize="36px" />
          </p>
        </BlockIconOption>
      </DivIconOption>
    </DivAuthor>
  </BlockAuthor>
  <BlockContaintPost>
    <ParagraphContaintPost>{post.postContent}</ParagraphContaintPost>
  </BlockContaintPost>
  <Separator/> {picturePost ?
  <BlockImagePost>
    <ImagePost src={post.imageUrlPostPicture || ' '} alt="photo profil utilisateur"></ImagePost>
  </BlockImagePost> : null} {picturePost ?
  <Separator/> : null}
  <BlockOptions>
    <IconLikeOn>
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={fasThumbsUp}/>
      <ButtonLike onClick={likeSystem}>
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={farThumbsUp}/>
      </ButtonLike>
    </IconLikeOn>
    <InputLike></InputLike>
  </BlockOptions>
</AllPostsAndModals>
))
```

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to do, but generally you'd have the rendered component respond to whatever event you're trying to work with. https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/responding-to-events

Comment: Ref specifically does not change (unless you change it) or cause re-renders which is its purpose https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/referencing-values-with-refs

Comment: I need to retrieve the id generated by MongoDB to be able to create a dynamic URL to create a like system, or a modification, or a deletion. Let the back know which post to change.